# Before The Mandalorian, what was the origin of Boba Fett's armor?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-mandalorian, boba-fett

In *The Mandalorian* episode "Chapter 14: The Tragedy", Boba Fett explains

> He was given his armor by his father, Jango Fett.

There are some pretty big differences between what's seen in *Attack of the Clones* and Boba's *Return of the Jedi* armor so I've always assumed that Boba got his armor another way - either by forging it himself, finding it, whatever.

Did *The Mandalorian* retcon a pre-existing origin? If so, what was the original origin (Disney canon and/or Legends)? If not, where did this explanation originate?

Comment: Also of note: I should think it would be rather difficult for Jango to "give" Boba the armour since, in SWII-AotC, Jango rather lost his head during the battle.

Comment: @elemtilas - That's not how you get ahead in life

Comment: The Ultimate Star Wars guide makes reference to Boba's armour being "a customised suit of Mandalorian armor" but no specific reference to it having belonged to his father. Note also that Jango's armor is explicitly called out as durasteel, not beskar (although this sudden obsession with beskar is relatively new in the Star Wars canon universe)

Comment: @elemtilas given the differences between the AOTC and ROTJ armour, its entirely possible that they are separate suits - the one we are familiar with might have been given to BF in JFs will for example, and that would satisfy both discrepancies (armour being different, backstory of "being given by his father" being different).

Comment: @Valorum - Sure he was quite beside himself!

Comment: He doesn't seem very headstrong.

Answer (score 3):

The two suits of armour have always generally been assumed to be the same one. There are a few discrepancies but they can be explained by Boba customising it along with years of wear and tear.

In *The Clone Wars* episode "R2 Come Home",  [Boba rigs his father's helmet to explode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUyNil49k_w) in an attempt to kill Mace Windu. The canon-ish *Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know* confirms that this is Jango's helmet, not a duplicate, so it may have been recovered, reforged, or replaced by the time of the original trilogy.

*Absolutely Everything* also says Boba "patches together" his own suit of armour, which might suggest he didn't have all the parts and had to improvise. If he had the helmet, he could reasonably have had the rest.

Overall, the story seems to be that Boba recovered his father's armour somehow and used it for himself, repairing and customising it as needed. The two armours look similar enough in *Attack of the Clones* and *The Empire Strikes Back* that I think that was always the intended interpretation.

How much he can replace and have it still be his father's armour is [one for the philosophers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus).